# Do I have ‘a family of five’ or ‘a family of six’?

Tags: word-choice, kinship-terms

I have a mom, a dad, two sisters, and a brother.

Do I write “I have a family of six” or “I have a family of five”?

In other words, do I include myself in the count?

Comment: What research is the OP expected to have done to make this question acceptable? Dictionary definitions of *family* do not obviously imply a definite answer to this specific question. The fact that experienced, established contributors to this site have confidently offered opposite answers to it shows that the matter is not straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your question and welcome to ELU.  jsw29 is making an important point.  The ELU , and the name implies, is about the way the English language is used.  so you need, in asking the question, to make clear what you have done to find out for yourself and why, having considered a dictionary and a grammar, you are unable to answer your own question.  Having said that, sometimes, however, ambiguity is hard to avoid and 'having a family' is one example of this.  The word 'family' can include all relatives, just the parents and their children.

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather say

> I ***come*** *from a family of **six***.

as your family has six members, not five.

If you insist on ***have***, then you can go for

> I have *a family of **five***

as the one who 'does *the having*' is excluded.

However, note that the variant with ***come*** is much more common:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the speaker is part of the family and should be included in its member count. The speaker has a family. The family consists of six people. Therefore, the speaker has a family of six. It is a family of six regardless of who is speaking, the size of the family is not dependent on who is commenting on it.

Without including the speaker, you get the odd situation where the family size depends on the speaker. If I am in a family of six people, not including the speaker would suggest that I have a family of five, my wife and I have a family of four, while the children have a family of two. I find this unintuitive - all of them have the exact same family, which includes themselves.

Not including the speaker makes the notion of family oddly variable. It would imply that with six people in the family, I have a family of five and so does my wife, but since those aren't the same five people, it means that my wife has a different family than I do.

Overall, though, there are more clear ways to phrase this, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a mom, a dad, two sisters, and a brother. Do I write “I have a family of six” or “I have a family of five”?

You do not write either. You have a family when you have children/grandchildren. Up until that time, you are "part of a family" and you include yourself in the total.

Comment: I agree.  “Part of a family six” or “from a family of six”

Comment: This is one sense of *to have a family*, but it is not the only one.

Answer (score -1):

In the usage you quote, you do not include yourself.

Consider the same pattern of usage in “I have no family”. This is said when someone has no close relatives. They have no spouse, no siblings, dead parents, no children, no aunts or uncles, no cousins.

The usage “no family” clearly does not apply to or include the speaker. Similarly, in “I have a family of five”, “a family of five” does not apply to the speaker, who is a member of a family of six.

If you need an inclusive statement, use “I am from a family of six” or “I come from a family of six”.

Comment: This sort of implies that "I have no family" and "I have a family of zero" mean the same thing, but I disagree. It also implies dependence on the number of speakers, leading to odd situations where a father who has a wife and two kids might say "I have a family of three", but the father and mother together would need to say "We have a family of two". I disagree with that, each individual has a family, and that family consists of four people - each one has a family of four.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Your first sentence: you may disagree but you give no reason. Your next proposition regarding "we" is not logical. "We" is a joint pronoun, so for a couple to say "we have ..." refers to what they jointly have; in this case two children, but more generally it could be two cars or three houses etc.  I agree your family consists of four, but the couple has a family of two.