# How do you refer to number of siblings?

Tags: count

If I had 3 brothers and 3 sisters, how would I refer to the number of siblings I have?

For instance, would I say, "I am the youngest of 6 siblings." Or would it be correct to say, "I am the youngest of 7 siblings?"

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, how would I refer to the number of siblings and still use the word siblings within the sentence? Or perhaps what would be a better way to word it?

Comment: siblings or children, there are still seven.

Comment: So, the right way to word it would be, "I'm the youngest of 7 siblings?"

Comment: Got it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I've deleted my comments and posted an answer instead.

Comment: Related: [Do I have ‘a family of five’ or ‘a family of six’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593605).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have three brothers and three sisters then you have six siblings in total. So it would be correct to say "I have six siblings".

Alternatively, if you use the expression "youngest of" then you are including yourself in the group, so then you would say "I'm the youngest of seven siblings". Three brothers plus three sisters plus yourself makes seven.

If you are not the youngest, you could indicate total number *and* how many are older than you by saying something like, "I'm the third of seven siblings".  Or if you don't wish to mention age, you can say, "I'm one of seven siblings". You could also say, "I'm one of seven children".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! This makes more sense, and I've accepted it as the answer.

Comment: Most of these don't need the actual word _sibling_; it's pretty rare. I have 3 brothers and 2 sisters, so I  normally just say that I'm the oldest of six. If I hafta use a noun, I'd use _kids_.

Comment: @JohnLawler - The OP had asked in a comment above about specifically including the word *sibling*. But yes, it's fine to omit the word if it's implied by context.

Comment: Got it, thank you both @JohnLawler @nnnnnn!